# How can i catch all exception in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How can I catch all the exceptions in an iPhone app and report to a central server?

I want to have access to the exception messages that occurred on devices (all devices that install my app).

Comment: Stackoverflow FAQ "open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: I think he's looking for some sort of global exception handler ...

Comment: 0x8badf00d, you really know nothing about objective-c.  One common programming task is to set an exception handler to handle all exceptions.  There is specific logic required to do this.  This question asks directly about how to perform this common objective-c programming task.  It is a tightly scoped question and there is one specific possible answer.  That answer is given below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your application delegate you can call [NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler) to install a handler to handle uncaught exceptions.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
}

void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, exception);
}
```

Comment: if I catch with this, does my app quit after that ?

Comment: @Entropy I found this answer when I was looking for what to do, it took me 5 seconds to determine the answer to your question when I'd plugged it in!

Comment: How can I use this for C++ exception and throw codes ?

Comment: @onmyway133, yes the app will quit after the execution of `uncaughtExceptionHandler`